# evaluate $\lim_{x,y \to 0,0} \frac{\sin(x+y)-(x+y)}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to evalute the following limit:

$\lim_{x,y \to 0,0} \frac{\sin(x+y)-(x+y)}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}}$

However , i have a problem. The answerkey of my textbook says that its limit is zero ,but wolfram-alpha says that limit does not exists.

Which answer is correct ? Can you help me to solve this limit.

Comment: Zero is correct.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Show that $\dfrac{\sin(x+y)-(x+y)}{x+y}\to0$.

Show that $0\le \left|\dfrac{x+y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right|\le2$

Comment: correct, I forgot absolute value

Comment: how can you separate them into two part, the second part has not limit value

Comment: wolfram says that the second part does not have limit value

Comment: @davidkenneth No need for wolfram, just let $y = kx$. Then $$\dfrac{x+y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \frac{1+k}{\sqrt{1+k^2}}$$ whose limit depends on the choice of $k$. So it does not exist. But Tito says just to find the bounds for that expression.

Comment: Use Squeeze Theorem, my firend @davidkenneth

Answer (score 1):

Using
$$ \sin t=t+\frac{1}{2}\cos(\xi)t^2, |a|\le\sqrt{a^2+b^2}, $$
where $\xi$ is between $0$ and $t$, one has
$$\bigg|\frac{\sin(x+y)-(x+y)}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}}\bigg|=\frac12\bigg|\frac{\cos(\xi)(x+y)^2}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}}\bigg|\le\frac12\frac{|x|+|y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}(|x|+|y|)\le|x|+|y|$$
from which one has
$$\lim_{x,y \to 0,0} \frac{\sin(x+y)-(x+y)}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}}=0$$

Comment: This seems so accurate! (+1)